# Has the TFS plugin for Jenkins been removed?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

I have been using Jenkins with the TFS plugin for several years but after installing Jenkins on a new machine, it seems that the TFS plugin cannot be found in the update center. All the other plugins that I could search for seem to work but not TFS, as if it had been deleted from there. I have tried using both jenkins-lts and jenkins weekly on two separate machines (both macs).

This is the plugin I am talking about: https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin

The old wiki page for it also seems to have been removed (I get a HTTP 403 Forbidden reply when trying to access that): http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin and the newer plugin index doesn't seem to know about this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/

I have tried to look on the Jira issue tracker but couldn't find anything that seemed relevant.

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after struggling with this for a while, I figured out what had happened.

There was a security issue for the TFS plugin that hasn't been fixed: https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2020-09-01/#SECURITY-1506

On top of that, it was found that the TFS SDK that is bundled with the plugin is not open source, which goes against Jenkins policy (see [INFRA-2751](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/INFRA-2751) for more details).

This means that the plugin has been removed from the update center in [this commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/5016) at the end of October 2020.

If the security issue is acceptable, the plugin can still be installed by [downloading the .hpi from Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/releases/latest) and then manually install the plugin in Jenkins: Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced > Upload Plugin and select the plugin file downloaded previously (Make sure to have git-plugin installed normally first so all additional dependencies are in place).

Thanks to the people on Jenkins Gitter that reminded me of the security issue as well as [@ian-w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598141/ian-w) on here that pointed at the actual problem.

Edit: I edited my answer to include Ian's comment.

2021-08-31: See additional details in this [S/O response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65165442/598141).

Comment: Not exclusively the Security issue. While a serious issue, lots of plugins remain with similar issues (although wisely used ones tend to get locked). The biggie is MS refusal to respond to the licensing terms for a packaged jar (tfs.sdk). See [INFRA-2751](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/INFRA-2751) and [code pull](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/5016). Speaking as a user, sad for M$ to just abandon their users since buying GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes sense now. I'm sure it's being handled but it would be great to have a message at the top of the readme on GitHub to prevent confusion. Removing the plugin from the installation wizard is also a good move. Hopefully the plugin can be refactored to have an external download of the SDK or similar but I'm not holding my breath... It might be time to abandon ship and join the Git party.

Comment: @Chamberlain what do you mean? I've just edited my answer to add Ian W comment so that it's clearer and easier to find.

Comment: @Uflex I mean you could mark your reply with a green check.