# Team Foundation Server plugin is not available in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, tfs

The Team Foundation Server plugin is not available in Jenkins. The Jenkins official page shows the message:

> Distribution of this plugin has been suspended due to unresolved security vulnerabilities

Is there any alternative to this plugin using which I can integrate Team Foundation Server with Jenkins?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MS have effectively abandoned support for TFVC and for the plugin.

You can still grab the plugin from the [GitHub TFS plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/releases) releases page and [upload manually](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation). (`{JENKINS_URL}/pluginManager/advanced` ). You may have to reconcile any dependencies manually.

MS recommended alternative is the `tf` command line from a shell step (brutal), which they also silently abandoned support for [TFS SDK/CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere).

ps: aside from the vulnerability ( [SECURITY-1506 / CVE-2020-2249](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2020-09-01/#SECURITY-1506) ), it does not meet the [OSI open source license requirements - INFRA-2751](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/INFRA-2751) to be made available via the plugins site.

2021-03-30: It appears the OSI licensing issue has been resolved. This [Jenkins Community post suggests a fix](https://community.jenkins.io/t/is-it-possible-to-integrate-tfs-into-jenkins/1106/2) to SECURITY-1506 / CVE-2020-2249 is available in a fork but additional security issues ( [SECURITY-2283 / CVE-2021-21636, CVE-2021-21637 (permission check), CVE-2021-21638 (CSRF)](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2021-03-30/#SECURITY-2283%20(1)) ) are outstanding, need to be resolved and released, or someone steps up to adopt the plugin.

pss: M$ also announced (23 February, 2021) retirement for [Azure plugins for Jenkins](https://github.com/azure-deprecation/dashboard/issues/132), effective February 29, 2024.

Comment: [@PatrickLu-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5391065/patricklu-msft), can you ask [leah antkiewicz](https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=leantk) if there might b e an update to [INFRA-2751](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/INFRA-2751). Lots asking for it, eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65406095/598141) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64897029/598141)

Comment: A little help here, Microsoft. People still use TFVC.