# Unable to find TFS plugin on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

Unable to find TFVC or Azure DevOps and Team Foundation Server plugin for Jenkins.
**Jenkins version - 2.263.1**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The official distribution of the TFS plugin has been suspended, because of security vulnerabilities. In the Jenkins plugin browser, you will not find it, however, it is available on GitHub under this link https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md. Personally, I wouldn't recommend the implementation, but everything depends on the needs.