# TFS integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, tfs

I am new and have little experience with Jenkins and TFS.

I was tasked to integrate TFS to Jenkins so we can automate our deployments.

But… Jenkins does not have a TFS plug in, is there any workaround ? I saw that the plug in for TFS was taken out because of vuln problems.

I have tried a little bit of everything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [the community ticket](https://community.jenkins.io/t/is-it-possible-to-integrate-tfs-into-jenkins/1106) from jenkins, the plug in was removed due to a licensing issue.

> Nevertheless, if you are prepared to accept the security risks, it is possible to [install manually](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation) by downloading from [GitHub release](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/releases) and installing. Make sure to have installed the [git-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) 3 first (as normal), which should pull in all the dependencies for you.

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157509/team-foundation-server-plugin-is-not-available-in-jenkins/65165442#65165442) for more information.